# Fast PostgreSQL query with GROUP BY, COUNT(DISTINCT) and SUM on differrent columns

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to query a table with approximately 1.5 million records. I have indexes and it performs well.

However, one of the columns I want to get a COUNT of a distinct column (that have many duplicates). When I do DISTINCT vs not its 10x slower.

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT
    created_at,
    SUM(amount) as total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT partner_id) as count_partners
FROM 
    consumption
WHERE
    is_official = true
    AND
    (is_processed = true OR is_deferred = true)
GROUP BY created_at
```

This takes 2.5s

If I make it:

```sql
COUNT(partner_id) as count_partners
```

It takes 230ms. But this is not what I want.

I want a unique set of partners per grouping (date) as well as a sum of the amounts they have consumed in that period.

I don't understand why this is so much slower. PostgreSQL seems to be very quick creating an array of all the duplicates, why does simply adding DISTINCT to it trash its performance?

**Query Plan**:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=85780.70..91461.63 rows=12 width=24) (actual time=1019.428..2641.434 rows=13 loops=1)
  Output: created_at, sum(amount), count(DISTINCT partner_id)" 
Group Key: p.created_at
  Buffers: shared hit=16487
  ->  Sort  (cost=85780.70..87200.90 rows=568081 width=16) (actual time=865.599..945.674 rows=568318 loops=1)
        Output: created_at, amount, partner_id
        Sort Key: p.created_at
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 62799kB
        Buffers: shared hit=16487
        ->  Seq Scan on public.consumption p  (cost=0.00..31484.26 rows=568081 width=16) (actual time=0.020..272.126 rows=568318 loops=1)
              Output: created_at, amount, partner_id
              Filter: (p.is_official AND (p.is_deferred OR p.is_processed))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 931408
              Buffers: shared hit=16487
Planning Time: 0.191 ms
Execution Time: 2647.629 ms
```

**Indexes**:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_pid ON consumption (partner_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_processed ON consumption (is_processed);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_official ON consumption (is_official);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_deferred ON consumption (is_deferred);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_created ON consumption (created_at);
```

Comment: Count queries can be difficult to optimize, but in any case you should include the index(es) you currently have on this table.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) of the slow query generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Please run `SELECT
    created_at,
    SUM(amount) AS total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT partner_id) AS count_partners
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        created_at,
        sum(amount) as amount,
        partner_id
  FROM consumption
  WHERE
    is_official = true
    AND
    (is_processed = true OR is_deferred = true)
  GROUP BY created_at,partner_id
  ) AS c

GROUP BY created_at;` and let me know how long it takes.

Comment: @Kendle Well that works, 341ms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should be able to benefit from the indexes.

```
SELECT  
  created_at,     
  SUM(amount) AS total,     
  COUNT(DISTINCT partner_id) AS count_partners 
FROM      
  (SELECT 
    created_at,         
    sum(amount) as amount,         
    partner_id   
  FROM consumption   
  WHERE is_official = true     
    AND (is_processed = true OR is_deferred = true)   
  GROUP BY 
    created_at,
    partner_id   
  ) AS c  
GROUP BY created_at;
```